# Select from a list passed to view in .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list

Before I had this:

```
public ActionResult ShowSong(int id)
    {
         return view(db.PublishedSongs.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

and in my view:

```
@model MusicSite.Models.PublishedSong
<h2>@Model.SongName</h2>
@Html.ImageFor(x => x.CoverImageBytes, @Model.SongName + " Image", new { @class = "big-cover-image" })
```

This worked fine for just retrieving one item from DB and showing on view.

However now, I need to also pass a list to my view, because I want to show all of the items in model **and** just the select item that was passed through action method, how do I do this?
If I pass `return View(db.PublishedSongs);` to view then I no longer know which id to get to show just that one item.

Comment: I guess this .NET MVC..I don't know syntactically but I can tell conceptually how i will fix this if it's spring MVC. what you said is correct you have to pass  `db.PublishedSongs` but to show selected id along with list you have to pass one more attribute i.e. the `id` you want to select. On view just iterate over the list by checking passed id is equal to id found while iteration if matched the make it as selected otherwise keep it as normal

Comment: Okay, how do I pass id and list though? You can only pass 1 item from controller to view. 

So something like this: return View(db.PublishedSongs, int id);

I don't know what value Id is either, because the user passes it through.

Comment: I am not an expert in .NET MVC but I remember something like `viewbag`. So idea is send list using `return View(db.PublishedSongs);` and add `id` in viewbag like `ViewBag.SelectId = id;` and on view you can access viewbag using `@ViewBag.SelectId`. Sorry if my syntax gone wrong. :)

Comment: Thank you! Never used viewbag before until now. That is correct.

Comment: If possible please update in answer that I given specially code in view, how to loop and syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am not that much good in .NET MVC but I will try to answer according to spring MVC knowledge.

The rough idea is to pass list to view as you are mentioned and along with it pass the id that you want to select using `ViewBag`. Now in view iterate over the list, while iteration check whether id come from iteration is equal to id that you passed in ViewBag.

So in controller :

```
public ActionResult ShowSong(int id)
{
   ViewBag.SelectId = id;
   return view(db.PublishedSongs);
}
```

In View :

```
(Loop over the db.PublishedSongs)
{
   if(PublishedSong.id=@ViewBag.SelectId)
   {
      //select current PublishedSong
   }
   else
   {
     //otherwise
   }
}
```